# Pandas find changes in column with datetime condition

Tags: python, pandas, performance, datetime

I have big DataFrame (1000000+ rows) with information about employees.

It`s contains information about employee id, date of recording and turnover status. If turnover not equal 1 than employee is currently working.

Here sample:

```
test_df =\
pd.DataFrame({'empl_id': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,3], 
              'rec_date':pd.to_datetime(['20080131','20080131','20080131', 
                                         '20080229', '20080229', '20080229', 
                                         '20080331', '20080331', 
                                         '20080430', '20080430',
                                         '20080531', '20080531', '20080531'], 
                                        format='%Y%m%d'), 
              'turnover':[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]})




+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|    |   empl_id | rec_date            |   turnover |
+====+===========+=====================+============+
|  0 |         1 | 2008-01-31 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |         2 | 2008-01-31 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  2 |         3 | 2008-01-31 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  3 |         1 | 2008-02-29 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  4 |         2 | 2008-02-29 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  5 |         3 | 2008-02-29 00:00:00 |          1 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  6 |         1 | 2008-03-31 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  7 |         2 | 2008-03-31 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  8 |         1 | 2008-04-30 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  9 |         2 | 2008-04-30 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| 10 |         1 | 2008-05-31 00:00:00 |          1 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| 11 |         2 | 2008-05-31 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| 12 |         3 | 2008-05-31 00:00:00 |          0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
```

I need to show whether the employee leaves the company after, for example, 2 months relative to the time specified in the record

I found solutions but it processing too slow. For DataFrame such size it will take more than 54 hours!

Here is my script:

```
    from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
    import calendar
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    # look only in employees with turnover
    res = test_df.groupby('empl_id')['turnover'].sum()
    keys_with_turn = res[res>0].index

    # function for add months
    def add_months(sourcedate,months):
        month = sourcedate.month - 1 + months
        year = sourcedate.year + month // 12
        month = month % 12 + 1
        day = min(sourcedate.day, calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1])
        return date(year,month,day)

    # add 2 months and convert to timestamp
    test_df['rec_date_plus_2'] = test_df['rec_date'].apply(lambda x: add_months(x, 2))
    test_df['rec_date_plus_2'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['rec_date_plus_2'])



    test_df['turn_nxt_2'] = np.nan

    for i in range(len(keys_with_turn)): # loop over employees ids
        for index, row in test_df[test_df['empl_id']==keys_with_turn[i]].iterrows(): # loop over all recs with employee
            a = row['rec_date']
            b = row['rec_date_plus_2']

            turn_coef = test_df[(test_df['empl_id']==keys_with_turn[i]) & 
                                ((test_df['rec_date']>=a) & (test_df['rec_date']<=b))]['turnover'].sum()

            test_df.loc[(test_df['rec_date']==a) & 
                        (test_df['empl_id']==keys_with_turn[i]), 'turn_nxt_2'] = 0 if turn_coef == 0 else 1     

    test_df['turn_nxt_2'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

The very result i`m looking for:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|    |   empl_id | rec_date            |   turnover |   turn_nxt_2 |
+====+===========+=====================+============+==============+
|  0 |         1 | 2008-01-31 00:00:00 |          0 |            0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|  1 |         2 | 2008-01-31 00:00:00 |          0 |            0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|  2 |         3 | 2008-01-31 00:00:00 |          0 |            1 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|  3 |         1 | 2008-02-29 00:00:00 |          0 |            0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|  4 |         2 | 2008-02-29 00:00:00 |          0 |            0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|  5 |         3 | 2008-02-29 00:00:00 |          1 |            1 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|  6 |         1 | 2008-03-31 00:00:00 |          0 |            1 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|  7 |         2 | 2008-03-31 00:00:00 |          0 |            0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|  8 |         1 | 2008-04-30 00:00:00 |          0 |            1 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
|  9 |         2 | 2008-04-30 00:00:00 |          0 |            0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| 10 |         1 | 2008-05-31 00:00:00 |          1 |            1 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| 11 |         2 | 2008-05-31 00:00:00 |          0 |            0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| 12 |         3 | 2008-05-31 00:00:00 |          0 |            0 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
```

How to do it faster and more Pandas way?

Comment: What about using `groupby` with `.min()` and `.max()` to get for every empl_id the first and last month in the dataframe. Then you can just calculate the difference. Avoid using `.iterrows()` if you want performance. (Still 54 hours seems excessive)

Comment: @niels-henkens, Good suggestion but employee can hire and quit multiple times during dataset

Comment: Ah, that makes it more complex

Comment: ^Maybe update your example data to show this caveat?

Comment: @user3471881 added such case in the end

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach could be to make a duplicated dataframe and merge on proper keys.

I made a simple code to demonstrate, although it can be improved on, here it is:

Starting from your original dataset we import a new library and convert the date type, so we can later on perform operations on it:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

DF_1 = pd.DataFrame({'empl_id': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2], 
              'rec_date':pd.to_datetime(['20080131','20080131','20080131', 
                                         '20080229', '20080229', '20080229', 
                                         '20080331', '20080331', 
                                         '20080430', '20080430',
                                         '20080531', '20080531'], 
                                        format='%Y%m%d'), 
              'turnover':[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]})

print (type(DF_1.rec_date[0]))
DF_1.rec_date = DF_1.rec_date.map(lambda X: X.date())
print (type(DF_1.rec_date[0]))
```

Now we make a duplicated dataframe with a merge column referencing the desired merge date for each entry

```
DF_2 = DF_1.copy()
DF_2['merge_value'] = DF_2.rec_date - relativedelta(months=2)
```

We also make a merge column on the original dataframe so the reference is easier within pd.merge

```
DF_1['merge_value'] = DF_1.rec_date.values
```

Now all we have to do is merge!

```
DF_1.merge(DF_2, on=['empl_id','merge_value'])
```

Another piece of advice is to try that first on a smaller sample, merge can sometimes present issues if what you thought were a primary key is not! (in this case, if there are multiple entries for the same combination of ['empl_id','merge_value'])

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. Crossjoins eats a lot of RAM on large datasets but it might be that time will be acceptable.

Comment: output not looking like something I want to do (:

Comment: output can be formated with droping and renaming columns, it can also result in something different than what you expected if the key was not primary (multiple entries for same ID & date)